Android foregound service not running every time
I have a foreground service to detect activity recognition changes, but looks the service sometimes going to sleep or something similar and that's why not working correctly. I added a "ping" log:
private val job = SupervisorJob()
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::Service")
    wakeLock?.acquire()

    scope.launch {
        while (true) {
            delay(60_000)
            Log.d("Service", "Running")
        }    
    }
}

And somitemes has more minutes between 2 ping, but later it's coming in every 60 seconds.

2024.07.29 21:27:40.16 - Running (428s)
2024.07.29 21:32:11.16 - Running (271s)
2024.07.29 21:34:36.16 - Running (144s)
2024.07.29 21:35:36.16 - Running
2024.07.29 21:36:37.16 - Running
2024.07.29 21:37:37.16 - Running
2024.07.29 21:38:37.16 - Running
2024.07.29 21:39:37.16 - Running
2024.07.29 21:40:37.16 - Running
2024.07.29 21:41:37.16 - Running

How can it be? How can I stabilize it? No battery saving mode or something similar

isPowerSaveMode: false
isDeviceLightIdleMode: true
isDeviceIdleMode: false
locationPowerSaveMode: 0
isLowPowerStandbyEnabled: false


Do you turn off screen while testing? The ForegroundService is not enough - you need to acquire a wake lock, so that CPU does not go to sleep.

Thanks. Yes, the screen can be off, this wanna be a 0-24 service. I added wakelock, but same result, some items is 60s, sometimes more like today morning e.g  Running (1139s)
I updated my post with wakelock code
